# Low Pass Filter using FPGA

Tags: electronic-filters

Does anyone know how to create the Verilog code for low pass filter in FPGA? I have no idea from where to start the project. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (even if it isn't homework). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: All I need is two clocks one with a reference frequency and another clock which acts as input which can change frequency from 50 MHz to 100mhz whenever we change the frequency to less than 50 MHz that wave passes through low pass filter. But I do not know how to code it in Verilog. Can you please help me ot?